# OneDrive not syncing on mac

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, office-365

I have OneDrive on my new computer and I have about 50gb to upload using the OneDrive client from the Mac App Store. It scans the files but always hangs after trying to upload a few kilobytes. Any help?

Comment: Can you login and transfer files without any problems through the OneDrive web portal?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have paid for additional OneDrive storage, you will only get 10 GB of storage to begin with. This may be why.

Also, you may want to contact Microsoft if you have paid for additional storage.

Comment: I have paid for 1tb of storage so I am certain that that isn't the problem. I think it has to do with the actual client software.

Comment: @woakley5 Is there a crash log available? Also, could you upload it through the web interface?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive for mac now has very good error messages. I would post the specific errors or uninstall the app, re-install it to get the latest client.

The major issue we face is copying in files that have illegal characters (according to OneDrive - not according to Apple)

If you have that specific error - see this question for options to bulk fix file and folder names.

- [How to remove leading whitespace in a folder for OneDrive upload on mac os](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398522/5472)

Also, using a modern browser to use the web app OneDrive and upload a file or look at errors can be a helpful trick when the app on your Mac is overwhelmed or not helping you out.