# How to remove leading whitespace in a folder for OneDrive upload on mac os

Tags: macos, finder, automator, office-365

I am currently transitioning my files from local to a OneDrive folder on my mac and after I have copied all of the files in I have hundreds of Sync issues which relate to file names containing spaces at the front.

I am fairly new to coding / automator and looking around on the internet is fairly daunting!

Is there an easy way to just select the folder you want and then remove all leading whitespace inside of that folder? I have used automator before but dont understand any of the coding associated.

My OneDrive folder sits in `Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨xxxxx` directory so is there a way of setting the folder there and then running something to remove all leading spaces?

If possible, a laymans guide would help! haha

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why do (or would) you have so many folders with *leading* whitespaces?  You can run a simple bash script to find them, but without seeing what you have and what you want to end up with would be difficult. Can you provide more solid  examples?

Comment: How did the "leading whitespace" get there? When you say "leading whitespace" are you talking about a _single space_, _multiple spaces_, same number of _spaces_ or a varying number of _spaces_?

Comment: Thanks for replying. An example would be `" Keynote Template.key"`. Its really annoying but the person naming the files (which were stored on a server), manually put spaces in front of files to sort them at the top of the folder. Not ideal!

Comment: We have this problem at work all the time. People put spaces in intentionally to get files to sort early, accidentally when they didn’t realize it. OneDrive is quite picky about some file names and we need to make this tool. If I have something I can release I’ll answer, but this is 100% a real thing people face.

Comment: Yes @bmike it is a common workplace issue and virtually impossible to manually adjust - unless I set aside a week to do it!

Comment: It can be fixed with an `awk` script in Bash. I’m not at my desktop at the moment, but it will only take a few moments to write out a script to remove the white spaces (rename the filenames). I wouldn’t do this in Automator, but with a bash script instead.

Comment: Thanks @user3439894. I think this seems to have worked. I realised there were a couple of folder names too that had spaces. Is it possible to edit this script for Folder names?

Comment: Great - that worked well. Thanks again! I just realised i have a space at the end of the file too for a lot of files. Is there an adjustment that would work as well?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that’s dedicated to fix this issue for OneDrive on the Mac.

- https://github.com/soundsnw/mac-sysadmin-resources/blob/master/scripts/fix-onedrive-filenames-apfs.sh

It is quite sophisticated and very well documented.

1. If you don’t have JAMF - remove those from the end - they fill fail harmlessly I believe if you don’t have the JAMF framework installed.
2. It checks for APFS and makes a full backup of the existing files.
3. It notifies you what it’s doing.
4. It fixes folders first, then files.
5. It trims white space from the front and end of files and folders and also corrects illegal characters like /
6. It tries to catch errors, clean up, prevent sleep, avoid spotlight going ballistic while the files are being renamed, etc..
7. There’s nothing about this script I don’t like, to be honest.

It has no warranty, but please ask if you think you need help modifying it. I did not write it, but the community of mac administrators that makes and shares these are some of the best resources I know for great tools.

Comment: thanks @bmike. Is it just a matter of running this in a terminal window?

Comment: I had a go and got the following error `> /jamf displayMessage -message "Something went wrong. A backup has been placed in FF-Backup-$fixdate in your user folder. Ask IT to help restore the backup."
> 
> fi
-bash: /jamf: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yes - you would comment those two lines out if you do not use JAMF - it just pops up a graphical warning or you could echo them ...